# ArcGIS Pro calculations combining joined and zonal statistics tables

Tags: arcgis-pro, attribute-table, attribute-joins, zonal-statistics, calculate-values

I have calculated the area of intersect/sum of intersect of rasters using zonal statistics by using province ID as a zone field. I now want to divide that summed data for each province, by the total tonnage of commodity production in each of the province's - which I have in a table joined to the original province attribute table.

Can anyone tell me how I go about dividing the values in one table by the values in another for each province?

I'm using ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Just add a new numeric field and then run the calculate field tool.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, is that a duplicate account, https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/209870/rachel?

Comment: Problem solved thank you. @fatih_dur Yes. I'm not sure how that happened! that question has since been deleted from this account.